# Select records which has no day-off throughout the week in List<T> - C#

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, enumerable

I have an `Employee` class which defined as this:

```
Employee
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public DateTime WorkDate { get; set; }
   public bool isOff { get; set; }
}
```

This is my class implementation and usage:

```
List<Employee> workers = new List<Employee>()
{
    new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "Emp 1", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/11/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "Emp 1", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/12/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "Emp 1", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/13/2016"), IsOff = true},
    new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "Emp 1", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/14/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "Emp 1", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/15/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "Emp 1", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/16/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "Emp 1", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/17/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new Employee { Id = 2, Name = "Emp 2", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/11/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new Employee { Id = 2, Name = "Emp 2", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/12/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new Employee { Id = 2, Name = "Emp 2", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/13/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new Employee { Id = 2, Name = "Emp 2", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/14/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new Employee { Id = 2, Name = "Emp 2", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/15/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new Employee { Id = 2, Name = "Emp 2", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/16/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new Employee { Id = 2, Name = "Emp 2", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/17/2016"), IsOff = false},
};
```

In the initialization above there is only 1 record that is off:

`Id = 1, Name = "Emp 1" and the WorkDate = 4/13/2016`

Now how can i get the id of an employee which has no day off throughout the week (from April 11-17)? Which is `Id = 2`

A `LINQ` solution is far better but i dont know how to do it.

> UPDATED

To avoid confusion of the object `Employee` i changed it to `EmployeeSchedule`

```
class EmployeeSchedule
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public DateTime WorkDate { get; set; }
   public bool isOff { get; set; }
}
```

This is the implementation

```
List<EmployeeSchedule> workers = new List<EmployeeSchedule>()
{
    new EmployeeSchedule{ Id = 1, Name = "Emp 1", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/11/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new EmployeeSchedule{ Id = 1, Name = "Emp 1", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/12/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new EmployeeSchedule{ Id = 1, Name = "Emp 1", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/13/2016"), IsOff = true},
    new EmployeeSchedule{ Id = 1, Name = "Emp 1", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/14/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new EmployeeSchedule{ Id = 1, Name = "Emp 1", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/15/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new EmployeeSchedule{ Id = 1, Name = "Emp 1", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/16/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new EmployeeSchedule{ Id = 1, Name = "Emp 1", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/17/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new EmployeeSchedule{ Id = 2, Name = "Emp 2", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/11/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new EmployeeSchedule{ Id = 2, Name = "Emp 2", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/12/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new EmployeeSchedule{ Id = 2, Name = "Emp 2", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/13/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new EmployeeSchedule{ Id = 2, Name = "Emp 2", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/14/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new EmployeeSchedule{ Id = 2, Name = "Emp 2", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/15/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new EmployeeSchedule{ Id = 2, Name = "Emp 2", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/16/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new EmployeeSchedule{ Id = 2, Name = "Emp 2", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/17/2016"), IsOff = false},
};
```

The selected answer is still applicable.

Comment: Is Lamda expression ok?

Comment: `var list = workers.Where(x => x.IsOff == false)` i dont know what extension must called to filter `Id = 2`

Comment: @Bharat i need `LINQ` sir.

Comment: i have added my answer,..@http://stackoverflow.com/users/6143656/shift-n-tab

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Now how can i get the id of an employee which has no day off
>   throughout the week (from April 11-17)? Which is Id = 2

You could use `Linq` extensions, and achieve this.

```
var empid = workers.GroupBy(g=> g.Id)           
                   .Where(x=>x.All(e=>!e.IsOff))
                   .Select(x=>x.Key)
```

Comment: You will need to change the `.Select(x=>x.Id)` to `.Select(x=>x.Key)` as you are working on the grouped elements.

Answer (score 4):

That means you need a `fromDate`,  `toDate`, and you have to find the employees from the list subject to the condition that, `WorkDate` should be in between `fromDate` and `toDate`, and also  `isOff == false` that means `has no day off throughout the week` So you can use the following snippet :

```
 DateTime fromDate = new DateTime(2016, 04, 11);
 DateTime toDate = new DateTime(2016, 04, 17);
 var noDayOfList = workers.GroupBy(x=> x.Id)
                          .Where(x =>
                                 x.All(y=> 
                                 y.WorkDate >= fromDate && 
                                 y.WorkDate <= toDate && 
                                 !y.isOff))
                          .Select(z=>z.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: This doesn't say they never have a day off in that period. It will return the days that aren't off, not the IDs

Comment: @Rob there is just a GroupBy(g=>x.id) required

Answer (score 3):

You can write something like this:

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2016,04,11);
var endDate = new DateTime(2016,04,17);

var ids = workers
    .Where(w => w.WorkDate >= startDate)
    .Where(w => w.WorkDate <= endDate)
    .GroupBy(w => w.Id)
    .Where(g => !g.Any(w => w.IsOff))
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Essentially:

1. Filter the rows you need (in this time frame)
2. Group by employee id
3. Make sure *none* of the rows in the group are marked `IsOff`
4. Select the grouping key (in this case, it'll be the Employee's Id)

Note though, it's a bit confusing calling the object `Employee`, as it really represents an employee's schedule, rather than an employee itself

Answer (score 2):

try, this you have two condition id and date but your id is sufficient for get your requirement,

```
List<string> resEmp = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in workers )
 {
     if (item.Id == 2 and item.IsOff == false)
      {
        resEmp.Add(item);
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at these code too.

i have defined a Model class of Employee to get the data,

maybe currently you need Id but in Future you can use another properties too.

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime WorkDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsOff { get; set; }
    }
```

and Code wtih Linq Expression,

```
 Employee objEmployee = new Employee();
 objEmployee.Id = workers
         .GroupBy(itm => itm.Id)
         .Where(itm => !itm.Any(m => m.IsOff))
         .Select(itm => itm.Key)
         .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This one is useful too