# LINQ: Get an item that is not in the records - C#

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, enumerable

This is an extended question back from my [`POST`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565288/select-records-which-has-no-day-off-throughout-the-week-in-listt-c-sharp/36565541#36565541)

```
class EmployeeSchedule
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public DateTime WorkDate { get; set; }
   public bool isOff { get; set; }
}
```

Now in this case i would like to find an `Id` whose `WorkDate` is not found in `4/12/2016` from the List as my criteria.

```
List<Staff> workers = new List<Staff>()
{
    new Staff { Id = 1, Name = "Emp 1", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/11/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new Staff { Id = 1, Name = "Emp 1", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/12/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new Staff { Id = 1, Name = "Emp 1", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/13/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new Staff { Id = 1, Name = "Emp 1", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/14/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new Staff { Id = 1, Name = "Emp 1", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/15/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new Staff { Id = 1, Name = "Emp 1", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/16/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new Staff { Id = 1, Name = "Emp 1", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/17/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new Staff { Id = 2, Name = "Emp 2", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/11/2016"), IsOff = false},
    // new Staff { Id = 2, Name = "Emp 2", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/12/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new Staff { Id = 2, Name = "Emp 2", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/13/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new Staff { Id = 2, Name = "Emp 2", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/14/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new Staff { Id = 2, Name = "Emp 2", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/15/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new Staff { Id = 2, Name = "Emp 2", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/16/2016"), IsOff = false},
    new Staff { Id = 2, Name = "Emp 2", WorkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/17/2016"), IsOff = false},
};
```

So far i have tried this code:

```
var notInDate = workers.Where(x => !workers.Any(y => Convert.ToDateTime("4/12/2016") != x.WorkDate));

foreach (var item in notInDate)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Id + " " + item.WorkDate.Date);
}
```

Which has the output of: `ID :1 WorkDate: 4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM`

And this one with this output:

```
var notInDate = workers.Where(x => workers.Any(y => Convert.ToDateTime("4/12/2016") != x.WorkDate));

ID :1 WorkDate: 4/11/2016 12:00:00 AM
ID :1 WorkDate: 4/13/2016 12:00:00 AM
ID :1 WorkDate: 4/14/2016 12:00:00 AM
ID :1 WorkDate: 4/15/2016 12:00:00 AM
ID :1 WorkDate: 4/16/2016 12:00:00 AM
ID :1 WorkDate: 4/17/2016 12:00:00 AM
ID :2 WorkDate: 4/11/2016 12:00:00 AM
ID :2 WorkDate: 4/13/2016 12:00:00 AM
ID :2 WorkDate: 4/14/2016 12:00:00 AM
ID :2 WorkDate: 4/15/2016 12:00:00 AM
ID :2 WorkDate: 4/16/2016 12:00:00 AM
ID :2 WorkDate: 4/17/2016 12:00:00 AM
```

The second example just removed the record whose `WorkDate is 4/12/2016`

I would like to get whose `Id = 2` because that `Id` do not have the `WorkDate` of `4/12/2016`

Comment: requirement is not clear enough,

Comment: i ll try to clarify my question sir

Comment: From what I see in the data posted there is an ID of 1 that also has a WorkDate of 4/12/2016, do you not want that one, just the one with an ID of 2?

Comment: @DavidY yes because `Id = 2` doest have a record of a given WorkDate criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want all entries from people that did not work on that day, you need to group by id (to get a group per person) and filter on individual groups that don't contain the date. Something like;

```
var notInDate = 
         // Create a group per employee
  workers.GroupBy (x => x.Id)
         // Keep only groups that didn't work
         .Where (x => !x.Any (y => y.WorkDate == Convert.ToDateTime ("4/12/2016")))
         // Get only the key for each group
         .Select (x => x.Key);
```

Comment: It is still a list of `Id = 2` but i achieved the result by editing your answer to this `var notInDate =
                              // Create a group per employee
                              workers.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                             // Keep only groups that didn't work
                             .Where(x => !x.Any(y => y.WorkDate == Convert.ToDateTime("4/14/2016")))
                             // Flatten the groups back to rows
                             .Select(x => x.Key);`

Comment: I would like to accept this answer please update it with the code i suggested

Answer (score 2):

You could do this, use `GroupBy` to group on `Id` and then validate whether staff worked on that date using `Any` extension..

```
var notInDate = workers.GroupBy(g=>g.Id)
                       .Where(x => !x.Any(y => DateTime.ParseExact("4/12/2016","M/d/yyyy", null) == y.WorkDate))
                       .FirstOrDefault();  // Get the first matching staff.
if(notInDate != null)
{
    id = notInDate.Key; // StaffId
}
```

Comment: sir it yield different result but i approved the answer of Joachim

Comment: it works, but i prefer the answer above sir big thanks!

Comment: No worries, I'm happy  as it helped you.